# Confusing in functions f(x)

Tags: math

I'm very sorry about the title, really had no idea what to put there!

I have this question :

[image: fx]

The answer is d, as explained :

> the initial value of x is a. This loop keep executing until f(y) = y,
>   through the condition to exit the loop was not indicated, but after
>   step (4) we have f(y) --> y, thus y = f(y)

I try to understand the explanation, but without success. I don't get it why in step 4, x = y, and return to step 2, y = f(x) , how come y=f(y) i don't get it !!!!

May anyony give me a clearer explanation please ?

Comment: This is a theoretical question in computer science not a programming question.

Comment: @RaymondChen it's a recursion problem

Comment: @XaxD It's a non-programming recursion problem. There is no code here that needs to be debugged. It's just a question about the theory of computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to bend your head around the control flow. Just formalize everything algebraically and let the mathematics guide you to the answer.

Let `x[i]` be the value of `x` at step 3 of iteration `i`.

Let `y[i]` be the value of `y` at step 3 of iteration `i`.

Step 2 implies

```
y[i] = f(x[i])                                 (1)
```

Step 4 implies

```
x[i+1] = y[i]                                  (2)
```

And "y is step 3 stops changing" means

```
y[i] = y[i+1]                                  (3)
```

Now stop thinking about the problem and just deal with the algebra.

```
y[i] = y[i+1]                                  restatement of (3)
     = f(x[i+1])                               applying (1)
     = f(y[i])                                 applying (2)
```

Comment: I watched you answer my question with dedication, i'm greatly appreciated. But honestly speaking, user3553031's answer is easier for me to understand, thanks alot !

Answer (score 2):

We aren't told what `a` or `f(x)` are.  We are only told that after some number of iterations of this loop, the value of `y` stops changing.  Since at every iteration of the loop, the value of `y` is set to `f(x)` and the value of `x` is set to `y`, the only possibility is that `y` reaches a value where `f(x)==y` on the next iteration.  Since `x` on the next iteration is `y` on the current iteration, this means that `f(y) == y`.

Answer (score 0):

Because at the point where Y stops changing, Y = X (see step 4), thus F(Y) = Y,

F(X) = Y and X = Y, thus F(Y) = Y